# Роутинг в веб приложении

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Мой вопрос следующий.

Традиционный путь использовать route "domain.com/user/create" В MVC паттерне для каждого пути есть свой view, путь, метод и т.д.. тут все ок.

Но также у нас появилось следующее "domain.com/#/user/create" (я про vue angular react ..)
Что как бы условно вымышленные пути для сервера, которые полностью отрабатывают на стороне юзера.

Вопрос в том это неправильно использовать оба эти способа одновременно?

То есть если у меня обычное MVC приложение на laravel но в определенных местах я хочу повыделываться и использовать второй способ который более юзер френдли.
Насколько это портит проект?
Нужно держатся одного пути в разработке или можно прыгать туда сюда?

Comment: эм, вообще не ясно. Вы же сами говорите, что первые пути ваши - сервер. Второй способ - пользовательская машина. Заходите вы, например, на site.com/news, а там загружается одностраничное приложение на vue. Где свои пути.

Answer (score -1):

Все зависит от вашей реализации, а правильно это или не правильно - покажет только время. Я не вижу ничего крамольного в совмещении 2-ух разных типов путей навигации по сайту, если в этом есть необходимость. Главное - все в меру, чтобы со временем у вас не стало 100500 различных принципов построения путей по сайту.